# Import css files and react components in a create-react-app application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm just starting with react.js and create-react-app application so excuse me if this is an obvious question.

My 'src' folder structure is like this:

```
scr/
....components/
........ComponentA.jsx
........Componentb.jsx
....styles/
........ComponentA.css
....App.css
....App.js
....App.test.js
....index.css
....index.js
...OTHER DEFAULT FILES
```

In App.js I have this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ComponentA from './components/ComponentA';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ComponentA />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In `ComponentA` I have this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles/ComponentA.css';
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB';

class ComponentA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="componentAStyle">
        <ComponentB />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentA;
```

In `ComponentB` I have this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ComponentB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello from ComponentB</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentB;
```

What I'm trying to do is just import `ComponentB` from `ComponentA` and also import the style for `ComponentA` but all this fall showing the following message:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/ComponentA.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve './styles/ComponentA.css' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\custom-k39\src\components'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

And if I remove the css import there is another error message:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/ComponentA.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/ComponentB' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\custom-k39\src\components'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

How can I import another component from another component and its respective css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the paths you are importing are relative to the current location of the file doing the import.

The correct imports would be

#### Component A

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/ComponentA.css';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';
```

You can see this working at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/trashy-unicorn.
(Click on Show Live in top left hand corner.)

Currently what is happening with your error is

```
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB';
```

is is looking in the path

```
src/components/components/ComponentB
```

which does not exist and so gives you an error. Same thing is happening with your styles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. But now how do you get positioned in 'src/' folder? e.g. How do you import a module located in root of 'src' folder from a component located in 'src/folderA/folderB/folderC/.../Component.jsx' ?

Comment: you can go back one folder level with '../'  

This is what happened with 
`import '../styles/ComponentA.css';`
It went back one level and then went to styles folder.

you can go back two folders with '../../' and so on. You'll need to count how far deep you are from your src folder and then keep adding '../'s until you get there.